# Can the note in §9.5.1 apply to non-class type?

Tags: c++, struct, standards, language-lawyer, unions

§9.5.1 States:

> [
> Note:
> One special guarantee
> is made in order to simplify the use of unions: If a standard-layout union contains several standard-layout
> structs that share a common initial sequence (
> 9.2
> ), and if an object of this standard-layout union type
> contains one of the standard-layout structs, it is permitted to inspect the common initial sequence of any of
> standard-layout struct members; see
> 9.2
> .
> —end note
> ]

There was some [questions elsewhere](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/304c6i/safe_bitfields_in_c/cpqain7?context=1) surrounding whether or not a non-class type and a standard-layout struct containing a member of that type as its initial sequence were layout compatible and covered under this guarantee.

Does the following code show undefined behavior?

```
struct S {
  int a;
};

union U {
  int a;
  S b;
};

int main() {
  U foo;
  foo.a = 3;
  return foo.b.a;
}
```

Comment: What is a "bare type"?

Comment: I don't see how that guarantee is relevant. It clearly talks about access to other standard-layout struct members, and an `int` is not a `struct` member.

Comment: Sorry, I meant literal type

Comment: I didn't see how a plain reading of the standard would imply that either.  However, I wasn't well versed in standard-layout structs, and although I read over 9.0.7 and didn't see anything, I didn't know if there were any guarantees elsewhere that would treat a literal type as equivalent layout to a standard-layout struct and allow the Note to apply somehow.

Comment: Thanks, if you throw that in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: The answer is not that clear... just saying. The type `int` is not a standard layout type, but there are guarantees that the layout is the same as `struct T { int x; };` which in turn makes it impossible for the compiler to do anything other than expected there. Yes, not explicitly guaranteed... not sure if this is not more a defect on the standard than an intended limitation. [Of course, the trivial non-answer is: *just wrap the `int` in a struct an then it will both work and be guaranteed, if you don't want the additional typing, make the struct an unnamed union]

Comment: Do you know where these layout guarantees are stated?  And isn't `union { int a; int b;} U;` `U.a = 0;` `return U.b;` also undefined?

Comment: @David Equivalent layouts are irrelevant. That note clearly and explicitly states that the permission is for inspecting other _structs_. Period. The only leeway you might find here is to locate the relevant normative text and see whether it's more ambiguous.

Comment: ... I don't know off the top of my head, and I don't have the drive to search through the standard at this point. The standard-layout guarantees make `T t; static_cast<void*>(&t) == static_cast<void*>(&t.x);` with `T`s definition above. @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I know it is not *guaranteed* (I already stated that above), but not sure if that is intentional or just a wording issue.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: We are discussing what the standard says, not what the standard could have said instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the behaviour is undefined. This has been the case in all C++ standard editions.

In C++14, for example, which was the standard in effect at the time this question was written, the special "common initial sequence" rules are found at [class.mem]/18. (The note quoted in the question, from [class.union]/1, is non-normative; notes in the C++ standard are always non-normative.) [class.mem]/18 says:

> If a standard-layout union contains two or more standard-layout structs that share a common initial sequence,
> and if the standard-layout union object currently contains one of these standard-layout structs, it is permitted
> to inspect the common initial part of any of them. Two standard-layout structs share a common initial
> sequence if corresponding members have layout-compatible types and either neither member is a bit-field or
> both are bit-fields with the same width for a sequence of one or more initial members.

`U` is a standard-layout union, but it doesn't contain two standard-layout structs. It contains one member `b` with standard-layout struct type `S`, and one member `a` of non-struct type `int`. The "common initial sequence" is only defined for two standard-layout structs; `a` does not have a common initial sequence with `b`.

Thus, attempting to read the value of `foo.b.a` is attempting to read the value of an object that is not alive, because `foo.b` is not alive because the `b` member is not active. This is UB under [basic.life]/6.